# Conditional statement to generate multi-column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace  values in columns  'Alloc1' and  'Alloc2' columns based on a condition in one column 'Number' in the below dataframe.

```
data = {'ID': ['001', '002', '003', '004'], 'Number': [99, 99, 20, 40], 'Alloc1': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], 'Alloc2': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]}
# Create DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My code to insert values based on the condition is below:-

```
for  numbers  in df["Number"]:
    
    if  (numbers == 99):
        df["Alloc1"] = 31
        df["Alloc2"] = 3

    else:
        df["Alloc1"] = 0
        df["Alloc2"] = numbers/2
```

The above seems to execute only the else part of the statement and  for the  last value in column "Number" that is not  99. How can I fix  this? A function will be  great. The ideal output  should  be:-

```
final = {'ID': ['001', '002', '003', '004'], 'Number': [99, 99, 20, 40], 'Alloc1': [31, 31, 0, 0], 'Alloc2': [3, 3, 10, 20]}
# Create DataFrame.
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final)
```

Comment: In your expected output, should `Alloc2` have values `3, 3, 10, 20` instead of `3, 3, 2, 2`? The logic implies that if `Number` is not 99, set `Alloc2 = Number / 2`

Comment: `df["Alloc1"] = 31` assigns the _entire column_ to a constant. You need to only assign the value in a certain row (the same row the number comes from) to the new values. A better approach, however, would be something like `np.where`.

Comment: Thank you @PeterLeimbigler for the correction. Edited  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think that the 'vectorized' solution will have better performance than this, and either that or the `where` version are more 'good pandas style'. This answer is just to show you how to achieve what you wanted using more like the approach you were following. This is not a very 'pandas' way to do things, but might be helpful in understanding why what you were trying didn't work.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ['001', '002', '003', '004'],
        'Number': [99, 99, 20, 40]}
        # Don't actually need the NaN-filled 'Alloc1' and 'Alloc2' yet
        # Those columns get created when you give them values, later
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def allocateCodes(row):
    if (row['Number'] == 99):
        row['Alloc1'] = 31
        row['Alloc2'] = 3
    else:
        row['Alloc1'] = 0
        row['Alloc2'] = row['Number'] / 2
    return row

# axis="columns" means go 'take each row' (i.e., a whole set of columns)
# at a time (can also use axis=1)
# instead of 'take each column' (axis="rows" / axis=0)      
outputDf = df.apply(allocateCodes, axis="columns")

print(outputDf)
```

Outputs:

```
    ID  Number  Alloc1  Alloc2
0  001      99      31     3.0
1  002      99      31     3.0
2  003      20       0    10.0
3  004      40       0    20.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this approach. It actually mirrors my thought process.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can safely overwrite the entire columns `Alloc1` and `Alloc2`, you can use `np.where` as Henry Ecker suggested:

```
df['Alloc1'] = np.where(df['Number'] == 99, 31, 0)
df['Alloc2'] = np.where(df['Number'] == 99, 3, df['Number'] / 2).astype(int)

print(df)
    ID  Number  Alloc1  Alloc2
0  001      99      31       3
1  002      99      31       3
2  003      20       0      10
3  004      40       0      20
```

Comment: This is way more elegant than mine, awesome.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Peter. Works well too.

Comment: Thanks @BaronLegendre. Your solution has the advantage that the reader doesn't need to think about how `np.where` works :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use **vectorized operation** to treat this problem

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ['001', '002', '003', '004'], 'Number': [99, 99, 20, 40], 'Alloc1': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], 'Alloc2': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]}
# Create DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Alloc1'] = 0
df['Alloc2'] = df['Number']/2
df.loc[df['Number'] == 99,'Alloc1'] = 31
df.loc[df['Number'] == 99,'Alloc2'] = 3
df
```

```
output
    ID  Number  Alloc1  Alloc2
0  001      99      31     3.0
1  002      99      31     3.0
2  003      20       0    10.0
3  004      40       0    20.0
```

Comment: Thank you Baron for  the solution. Works  well too.